# GroupBy() to master detail relationship

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, combobox

I am stuck at creating a master detail relationship in C# WPF, between combobox (parent) and listview (child) controls using Linq.

```
protected class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender{ get; set; }
}

protected static List<Student> students = new List<Student>
{
   new Student {FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams", Gender= "M"},
   new Student {FirstName = "Terry2", LastName = "Adams", Gender= "M"},
   new Student {FirstName = "Karry", LastName = "Adams2", Gender= "F"},
   new Student {FirstName = "Karry2", LastName = "Adams4", Gender= "F"},
}
```

Combobox will be generated by the Gender groubby(), and listview will be updated based on combobox selection. Something like this but in is not working, Thank you

```
var result = (from cat in students 
               select new {
               FirstName = cat.FirstName ,                                         
               LastName = cat.LastName}).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Your linq seems to be collecting distinct first and last names, Where does group by come into this? and your combobox selection?

Comment: I am just experimenting on syntax..... As far as I understand I need to create a hirearchical data, Gender -> Student and when bind Gender to Combobox and Listview to Gender.Students

Comment: Ok so you want combobox to display *only* the different gender types, and the list view to display those students whose gender matches selection

Comment: Yes, this is basic idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be better ways to actually set the data in listview, comboboxes but I'm not too familiar with WPF, the linq's seem right though.

```
    comboBox1.ItemsSource = students.Select(x => x.Gender).Distinct(); 

    private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.ItemsSource = students
            .Where(x => x.Gender == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()).ToList();
    }
```

Student needs to override ToString()

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);        
    }
```

Comment: @Jim - Glad it worked :) I was unsure about resetting the item source of listview every selection but I can't think of another way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this ?

**Sample code :**

```
var result = (from cat in students
                          select new
                          {
                              FirstName = cat.FirstName,
                              LastName = cat.LastName,
                              Gender = cat.Gender

                          }).Distinct().ToList().Where(oc=>oc.Gender == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: Not sure if I get it but I need to create two results one for Gender = "M" and the other  for Gender="F"?

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:

```
//For Combobox (You can
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        var AllGender = (from cat in students select cat.Gender).Distinct();
        foreach (var gender in AllGender)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(gender.ToString());
        }
    }
//For ListBox
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedValue = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var studentList = from student in students 
                          where student.Gender == selectedValue 
                          select new { Firstname = student.FirstName, LastName = student.LastName };
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var student in studentList)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(student.Firstname + " " + student.LastName);
        }

    }
```

Hope it helps.